# For a multi-key partition in amazon athena, does order matter?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, partition

When setting up amazon athena partitions to be used with Partition Project with a glue catalog.  Does the order of partitions within the S3 bucket matter?

**Example partition strategies:**

- Partition by year/month/day. `s3://year=2022/month=01/day=21`
- Partition by day/month/year. `s3://day=21/month=01/year=2022`

**Scenario 1:**  A query specifies year, month and day.  Does one partition strategy execute the query faster?  Does one partition strategy incur less costs - I imagine data scanned costs are the same, but what about costs incurred from S3 operations?

**Scenario 2:**.  A query only specifies day.  Does one partition strategy execute the query faster?  Does one partition strategy incur less costs - again, I imagine data scanned costs are the same, but what about costs incurred from S3 operations?

Answer (score 0):

Remember S3 has a flat structure, folder is an illusion, there is only bucket and key.

```
s3://year=2022/month=01/day=21/<100 files> = 100 obj
s3://year=2022/month=01/day=22/<100 files> = 100 obj


s3://day=21/month=01/year=2022/<100 files> = 100 obj
s3://day=22/month=01/year=2022/<100 files> = 100 obj
```

for query where day = 21, in any order, 100 keys need to be read.

for query where year = 2022, 200 times read anyway.

not 100% sure but this is my reasoning.

ref. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html

Comment: Your answer is vague. It would be very useful to the person asking the question if you make the answer more clear and explain the answer more.